# java.io.invalidClassException - which class is causing it?

Tags: java, serialization

I am getting an InvalidClassException when trying to open a serialized class. The class I am trying to open is quite complex and contains several other classes. Is there any way of telling which class is causing the exception?

I have set serialVersionUID on all classes and used transient variables where necessary. Presumably I have failed do to this for all classes, but I would like to find a way of locating the error without having to read through the code for every class.

Here is the stack trace I'm getting:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: javax.swing.event.EventListenerList; local class incompatible: stream classdesc serialVersionUID = -5677132037850737084, local class serialVersionUID = -7977902244297240866
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.initNonProxy(ObjectStreamClass.java:728)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readNonProxyDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:2086)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readClassDesc(ObjectInputStream.java:1933)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2259)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1768)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$FieldValues.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:2641)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readFields(ObjectInputStream.java:725)
    at java.desktop/javax.swing.tree.DefaultTreeModel.readObject(DefaultTreeModel.java:704)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectStreamClass.invokeReadObject(ObjectStreamClass.java:1231)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2458)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2292)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1768)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream$FieldValues.<init>(ObjectInputStream.java:2641)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readSerialData(ObjectInputStream.java:2492)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(ObjectInputStream.java:2292)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(ObjectInputStream.java:1768)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:543)
    at java.base/java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(ObjectInputStream.java:501)
    at combined.CombinedInterface.open(CombinedInterface.java:82)
    at combined.CombinedInterface.main(CombinedInterface.java:18)
```

Also, this problem doesn't occur when I'm running the program in NetBeans, it only occurs when I'm running it from a jar file outside of Netbeans.

Comment: I would *suspect* `javax.swing.event.EventListenerList` from the start of the exception (I am also pretty sure that most Swing classes have a warning regarding serialization (something like incompatibility with future versions)

Comment: @user16320675 Ah. It seems obvious now! Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The class that is causing this is `javax.swing.event.EventListenerList`.

Note that you should generally avoid serializing Swing classes.  Many Swing classes state this in their javadocs:

> *"Serialized objects of this class will not be compatible with future Swing releases."*

So if your use-case entails serializing with one version of Java and *potentialiiy* deserializing with another version, you are liable to run into this kind of problem.

Comment: Thanks - yes, the Swing class shouldn't have been serialized, it was supposed to be a transient variable. I hadn't noticed the error before because presumably I was serializing and deserializing with the same version of Java so it wasn't causing a problem.